# How to Switch Views

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, view, instruments

I know this has been answered before in different ways, but I am a novice programmer and really need some contextual help. I have a basic application that has multiple view controllers (.h, .m, .xib each. EX. about.h, about.m, about.xib, options.h, options.m, etc.). I need to switch between them on the press of a button.

I had been using:

```
xxxViewController *titleScreen = [[xxxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"xxxViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:titleScreen.view];
    [xxxViewController release];
```

and it worked fine to switch the views. But then I noticed that in Instruments, the overall/net bytes kept climbing, without "releasing" the view that it came from.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help... I'm desperate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't switching views, you're just just adding one on top of the other that way.  If you want to navigate between different views, chances are, you want [a navigation controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1).

Comment: Thank you! But I don't want a bar in my application. Is it possible to make it invisible? (sorry if this is a novice question... I **am** a novice, sadly)

Comment: I checked this out in the apple documentation, and profiled the "drilldownsave" sample project, and it faces the same problem: every time you access a new view, it simply puts it on top, adding more memory but not getting rid of the old. I don't think this is what I need sadly.

Comment: It's not the same problem.  The views aren't simply placed on top of one another.  The view controllers are kept in memory as they need to maintain state, but if iOS is running low on memory, the views are released, as the view controllers can recreate them when necessary.  Check it yourself by issuing a memory warning in the simulator.

Comment: ohh ok. Yeah for the past few hours I have been trying independently to do something similar to that and eventually fell upon [self.view removeFromSuperView]; and it does basically what I want with less work.